# nuGet-Package incomplete? e.g. class Westwind.Globalization.JavaScriptResourceHandler is missing

Tags: globalization, nuget-package, westwind

I installed the Westwind-Globalization package 2.1 but the libraries installed are misssing the Westwind.Globalization.JavaScriptResourceHandler-class. I downloaded 2.1 from git-hub and compiled the Westwind.Globalization.Web-project anew. Now the class exists and my code works again.

Did I do something wrong or is this class deprecated/discontinued?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Westwind.Globalization.Web package, which includes the JavaScript resource handler. The release version of the libary rearranged the breakout of resources into separate packages. I suspect you had an older, or beta version that came from before when the change was made (a beta most likely).